# Java AWT list box

Tags: java, awt

I was implementing a pure AWT list box. If the items inside the list box are more than it can accommodate then it creates a scroll bar.  I want to customize the scroll bar and place a user defined image over the scroll bar.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use Swing.  There are wheels worth reinventing, and this aint one of them.

Comment: i know i can use Swings. But our client want us to implement this in AWT only

Comment: Then take the Swing source code, file off the serial numbers, and present it as your own.

Comment: @Junaidaj in most cases is not possible to change all AWT properties, because AWT is based on methods that came from Native OS

Comment: *"our client want us to implement this in AWT only"* **Why?**

Comment: dont know but they require it should be in AWT

Comment: *dont know*  Ask them!  This project will cost more to develop and more to maintain if using the AWT.  As a professional, it is your responsibility to to ask the tough questions the client may not have thought of.  Please also note that I will not be informed of your comment unless you prefix it with @and, the only reason I saw this is because you asked another question & I remembered you (I was going to berate you for ignoring me, but thought I should check first).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson :Ok, will follow the guideline. They already have a app with is built on AWT and they want us to improve the GUI using that old technology.

Comment: Thanks, got a notification of that comment!  BTW - there are some cases where it is not necessary.  In those cases, the site software will automatically remove it.

Comment: As to the 'built on AWT'.  1)  It used to be a no-no to mix Swing and AWT.  From Java 7, it can be done without problem.  Can they justify specifying the minimum JRE as 7? 2) If not, it might be cheaper to recode that single component that contains the list to use Swing.  Swing and AWT *could* be mixed in earlier JREs, so long as the component was entirely contained in a top level component.  e.g a frame using Swing could pop a dialog using AWT, without any problems.