# AWT Dialog resize

Tags: java, awt

I am implementing an AWT dialog. This dialog is popped when we click a settings button. Initially the dialog has a size of 750x300. When I click on a button inside the dialog then the size should increase to  900x300.

How can I dynamically resize this `Dialog`?

PS: No swing

Comment: What is the answer to the question I asked in the last comment on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866465/java-awt-list-box)?  I don't often ask rhetorical questions, and that was **not** one of the few.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following?

1. Change your dialog box size to the new one you want
2. Call `dialog.pack()` to re-position all internal UI elements

Regards,
Tahar

Answer (score 1):

> How can I dynamically resize this `Dialog`?

Pretty much the same as you might do in a `JDialog` (or `Window` or `Frame` or..).

[`Window.setSize(Dimension)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29)